# (Python) problem combine 2 function together make USB can be detected, write and read

Tags: python, usb

*problem with combine two function together* to make USB can be detected, write and read. I tried that two function before combine together can run successfully.

USB path to file 1111.txt is:

> /media/joy/Data/1111.txt

**Function1 (run successfully)- detect the last/new plug USB  (then extract new USB's idVendor and idProduct )**

```
import time
from usb.core import find
from usb.util import get_string
import usb.backend.libusb1
import re

def info_usb_device(dev):
    xdev = find(idVendor=dev.idVendor, idProduct=dev.idProduct)
    if xdev.bDeviceClass == 9:  # don't list HUBs, see [USB class-codes](https://www.usb.org/defined-class-codes)
        return
    if xdev._manufacturer is None:
        xdev._manufacturer = get_string(xdev, xdev.iManufacturer, langid=1033)
    if xdev._product is None:
        xdev._product = get_string(xdev, xdev.iProduct, langid=1033)
    device_info = '[%20s] %8d %9d %s - %s' % (xdev.serial_number, dev.idVendor, dev.idProduct,
                                 str(xdev._manufacturer).strip(),
                                 str(xdev._product).strip())
    return xdev.serial_number, device_info 


def add_usb_devices(device_dict):
    new_devices = []
    for bus in usb.busses():
        for dev in bus.devices:
            if dev is None:
                continue
            serial_info = info_usb_device(dev)
            if serial_info is not None:
                (serial, info) = serial_info
                if serial not in device_dict:
                    new_devices.append(serial)
                    device_dict[serial] = info
    return new_devices


if __name__ == "__main__":
    device_dict = {}
    print('%22s %8s %9s %s' % ('serial', 'idVendor', 'idProduct', 'Manufacturer - Product'))
    print('-'*22, '-'*8,  '-'*9, '-'*30)
    # first scan
    add_usb_devices(device_dict)
    for device_info in device_dict.values():
        print(device_info)
    # next scans
    for i in range(5):  # run 5 more scans 
        new_serials = add_usb_devices(device_dict)
        if len(new_serials) > 0:
           print('** (scan %d) FOUND NEW USB DEVICES/SERIALS: %s' % (i, new_serials))
           for serial in new_serials:
               print(device_dict[serial])
        time.sleep(3)  # waiting 3 seconds before new scan
        
    str_device_dict_serial = device_dict[serial]
    listed__device_dict_serial = re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', str_device_dict_serial)
    
    #splited_str_device_dict_serial= str_device_dict_serial.split(" ")   
        
     
    print('Scans completed.')
    
    print("+ + + + + + + + + + + + +")
    print(device_dict[serial])
    print(listed__device_dict_serial)
```

**Function2 (run successfully)- USB file read&write**

```
import usb.core
import usb.util
import os
import numpy as np


def USB_file_write(input_idVendor, input_idProduct):

    input_idVendor = listed__device_dict_serial[0]
    input_idProduct = listed__device_dict_serial[1]

    #use last function detected idVendor, idProduct 
    dev = usb.core.find(idVendor= input_idVendor, idProduct=input_idProduct)

    ep = dev[0].interfaces()[0].endpoints()[0]
    i=dev[0].interfaces()[0].bInterfaceNumber
    dev.reset()

    if dev.is_kernel_driver_active(i):
        print("hello user")
             

    more_lines = ['', 'new data 1', 'new data 2']

    #USB path to file 1111.txt is /media/joy/Data/1111.txt
    with open("/media/joy/Data/1111.txt", 'a') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(more_lines))


    data_inside_content2222222 = np.loadtxt("/media/joy/Data/1111.txt", dtype='str' , delimiter=",")
    return data_inside_content2222222


def USB_file_read():
    current_directory = os.getcwd()
    content2222222 = os.listdir("/media/joy/Data")
    contents = os.listdir(current_directory)
    return content2222222


print(data_inside_content2222222)
print("the file in the same directory is: ")
print(content2222222) 

# ️ check if file in current directory
print('example-file.txt' in contents)
```

> Function1 successfully return idVendor and idProduct['34148', '4096'] that for Function2 to read and write inside the USB txt file
>
> **the problem seems occur in Function2**
> and I tried to give input in `USB_file_write()`    , still get error

**(pls help me from here) When I compare Function1 and Function2 there is an error:**

```
import time
from usb.core import find
from usb.util import get_string
import usb.backend.libusb1
import re
import usb.core
import usb.util
import os
import numpy as np

def info_usb_device(dev):
    xdev = find(idVendor=dev.idVendor, idProduct=dev.idProduct)
    if xdev.bDeviceClass == 9: 
        return
    if xdev._manufacturer is None:
        xdev._manufacturer = get_string(xdev, xdev.iManufacturer, langid=1033)
    if xdev._product is None:
        xdev._product = get_string(xdev, xdev.iProduct, langid=1033)
    device_info = '[%20s] %8d %9d %s - %s' % (xdev.serial_number, dev.idVendor, dev.idProduct,
                                 str(xdev._manufacturer).strip(),
                                 str(xdev._product).strip())
    return xdev.serial_number, device_info 


def add_usb_devices(device_dict):
    new_devices = []
    for bus in usb.busses():
        for dev in bus.devices:
            if dev is None:
                continue
            serial_info = info_usb_device(dev)
            if serial_info is not None:
                (serial, info) = serial_info
                if serial not in device_dict:
                    new_devices.append(serial)
                    device_dict[serial] = info
    return new_devices


if __name__ == "__main__":
    device_dict = {}
    print('%22s %8s %9s %s' % ('serial', 'idVendor', 'idProduct', 'Manufacturer - Product'))
    print('-'*22, '-'*8,  '-'*9, '-'*30)
    # first scan
    add_usb_devices(device_dict)
    for device_info in device_dict.values():
        print(device_info)
    # next scans
    for i in range(5):  # run 5 more scans 
        new_serials = add_usb_devices(device_dict)
        if len(new_serials) > 0:
           print('** (scan %d) FOUND NEW USB DEVICES/SERIALS: %s' % (i, new_serials))
           for serial in new_serials:
               print(device_dict[serial])
        time.sleep(3)  # waiting 3 seconds before new scan

    str_device_dict_serial = device_dict[serial]
    listed__device_dict_serial = re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', str_device_dict_serial)

    #splited_str_device_dict_serial= str_device_dict_serial.split(" ")   


    print('Scans completed.')

    print("+ + + + + + + + + + + + +")
    print(device_dict[serial])
    print(listed__device_dict_serial)





def USB_file_write(input_idVendor, input_idProduct):

    

    #use last function detected idVendor, idProduct 
    dev = usb.core.find(idVendor= input_idVendor, idProduct=input_idProduct)

    ep = dev[0].interfaces()[0].endpoints()[0]
    i=dev[0].interfaces()[0].bInterfaceNumber
    dev.reset()



    more_lines = ['', 'new data 1', 'new data 2']

    #USB path to file 1111.txt is /media/joy/Data/1111.txt
    with open("/media/joy/Data/1111.txt", 'a') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(more_lines))


    data_inside_content2222222 = np.loadtxt("/media/joy/Data/1111.txt", dtype='str' , delimiter=",")
    return data_inside_content2222222

data_inside_content2222222_print = USB_file_write(listed__device_dict_serial[0],listed__device_dict_serial[1])


def USB_file_read():
    current_directory = os.getcwd()
    content2222222 = os.listdir("/media/joy/Data")
    contents = os.listdir(current_directory)
    return content2222222

print(data_inside_content2222222_print)
print(data_inside_content2222222)
print("the file in the same directory is: ")
print(content2222222) 

# ️ check if file in current directory
print('example-file.txt' in contents)
```

and the output:(TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable) cause `dev` is None. The return value from `interfaces()` lead to None. The return value from `endpoints()` lead to None.

```
(base) joy@joy-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo python '/home/joy/fe_dir/combined_function.py'
                serial idVendor idProduct Manufacturer - Product
---------------------- -------- --------- ------------------------------
[                None]     1133     49271 Logitech - USB Optical Mouse
[             2004888]     1423     37728  - USB Reader
[5334354E373539325A315A4B]     5117      2112 Generic - External
** (scan 2) FOUND NEW USB DEVICES/SERIALS: ['01DZTW5EXY5TSUF8']
[    01DZTW5EXY5TSUF8]    34148      4096 JetFlash - Mass Storage Device
Scans completed.
+ + + + + + + + + + + + +
[    01DZTW5EXY5TSUF8]    34148      4096 JetFlash - Mass Storage Device
['34148', '4096']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joy/fe_dir/combined_function.py", line 96, in <module>
    data_inside_content2222222_print = USB_file_write(listed__device_dict_serial[0],listed__device_dict_serial[1])
  File "/home/joy/fe_dir/combined_function.py", line 80, in USB_file_write
    ep = dev[0].interfaces()[0].endpoints()[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Just look at the error message. It tells you all you need to know. **TypeError: USB_file_write() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'input_idVendor' and 'input_idProduct'**

Comment: hi @OldBill, I tried to give input in USB_file_write(), still have other type of error

Comment: Look at the error: **TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable** There are three reasons why this could be occurring. *dev* may be None. The return value from *interfaces()* may be None. The return value from *endpoints()* may be None. Break the code down into those three parts and test each value before trying to subscript it

Comment: yeah @OldBill, that my dev is none when I run in combined function, but just run in Function1 is work that dev isn't empty. Now the problem is that not sure how to avoid dev is none in  combined function